# How to generate a column with id which increments on every insert

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, ado.net

This is my table where i want my PNRNo to be generated as 'PNRRES001' for the first entry, and consecutive entries with 'PNRRES002','PNRRES002' so on.
So while creating table only i called that column to function which will generate the PNR no, User just has to enter the CustomerNo from the front end, and data wit PNR & Customer No will updated to the PNRDetails table.

```
CREATE TABLE PNRDetails(PNRNo AS (DBO.FuncIncPNR()) ,customerNo INT

--FUNCTION TO GENERATE THE PNR NUMBER
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.FuncIncPNR()
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @RR VARCHAR(20) SET @RR='PNRRESA001'
--here i have checked if no value is there then return the first value as 'PNRRESA001'
    IF((SELECT COUNT(*)FROM PNRDetails)=0)
    BEGIN
    RETURN @RR
    END
    ELSE
-- if any value is there then take the last value and add 1 to it and update to the table
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @pnr VARCHAR(20),@S1 VARCHAR(20),@S2 INT
    DECLARE PNRCursor CURSOR Static
    FOR SELECT PNRNo FROM PNRDetails
    OPEN PNRCursor
    FETCH LAST FROM PNRNo INTO @pnr
    SET @S1=SUBSTRING(@pnr,1,7)
    SET @S2=RIGHT(@PNR,3)
    SET @S2=@S2+1;
    SET @pnr=@S1+@S2;

    END
    RETURN @pnr
END

--Here am inserting only customerNo as 5 and the PNR should be generated by my function
INSERT INTO PNRDetails VALUES(5)
--it shows 1 row updated  :)
SELECT * FROM PNRDetails
-- but when i run select command it shows
--Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).  :(
```

U can run this.And pls do help if u find anything that could help me. any help will be appreciated...
Waiting for your kind response...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are happy to change the table structure. Following will do the job.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PNRDetails](
[autoId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[prnNo]  AS ('PNRRES'+right('000'+CONVERT([varchar](3),[dbo].[GetRowCount]([autoId]),(0)),(3))),
[customerNo] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[autoId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**EDIT:** to address identity issue for your requirement pls create following function and pass the [autoId] in as above (edited) in the computed column.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetRowCount
(
@autoId INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @RESULTS AS INT
SELECT @RESULTS = COUNT(autoId) FROM PNRDetails WHERE PNRDetails.autoId<@autoId
    RETURN @RESULTS + 1
END
GO
```

--INSERT

```
INSERT INTO PNRDetails (customerNo) VALUES(5)
```

Comment: Please replace **Table1** with **PNRDetails**

Comment: Thanks for the kind response, But 1 drawback with the identity is if i insert any value to the table and if any point i ROLLBACK, The gap is created, So i am trying to avoid IDENTITY...

Comment: I have edited as you need. Please note that is not persistent. i.e. if you delete a row at any time customerNo will be changed as the function returns a row count. If you need it to be persistent simply change it in the design view of the table. Design view > select customerNo column > change persistent to yes.

Answer (score 6):

You could try to use a computed column and an identity column instead.

```
create table PNRDetails
(
  ID int identity,
  PNRNo as 'PNRRES'+right(1000+ID, 3),
  customerNo int
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the kind response, But 1 drawback with the identity is if i insert any value to the table and if any point i ROLLBACK, The gap is created, So i am trying to avoid IDENTITY..

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest just using an [IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) instead as your id, let SQL Server handle the assignment of each id number with all it's built-in guards for concurrency, and leave the formatting up to the UI....or,  create a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) that defines the formatted version of the ID if you really do need it in the DB.

The risk you run with your intended approach is:

- poor performance
- concurrency issues - if loats of ids are being generate around the same time

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use an identity column in your database (INTEGER)

> PROS: easy/No gaps in between generated ids
>
> CONS: You have to select the inserted id & return via procedure/query
>   if you were to show it to end user

2) Define a database sequence

> PROS: easy to implement/Can be stored/shown to user before the form is
>   even saved
>
> CONS: Gaps in between if the certain id is once generated & not used

3). Select max(id) from column + 1

> PROS: Useful where only single user inserts in a table
>
> CONS: disastrous if you were in an environment where multiple users
>   were inserting in the same tablle (mismatched max ids)

4) Use a database trigger to autoincrement the column

> PROS:automated
>
> CONS: hard to debug (you have to make sure it don't breaks for some
>   reason otherwise insert fails)

Comment: I didn't vote you down, but there are at least two errors in your answer: using IDENTITY does not prevent gaps (point 1) and database sequences are not available until SQL Server 2012 but the OP asked about 2005/2008 (point 2).

Comment: @Pondlife thanks for the info. Can you explain how can an identity field has gaps when the transaction is rolled back ? Also, I overlooked the person was using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Try it and see: if you ROLLBACK an INSERT on a table with an IDENTITY column, the newly generated value is lost and a gap is created. The documentation also says that frequent DELETEs may cause gaps. And of course, you can explicitly change the current 'seed' with DBCC CHECKIDENT or insert specific values using SET IDENTITY_INSERT. So by itself, IDENTITY does not prevent gaps (and it is not guaranteed to be unique, which is the other big misconception about it). If you really need gapless sequences, you usually have to roll your own code.

Comment: Thanks Pondlife. It was very informative what you said about deletes, I totally overlooked them. Everyday is a learning day, Thank you once again =)

Comment: Thanks for the kind response, But 1 drawback with the identity is if i insert any value to the table and if any point i ROLLBACK, The gap is created, So i am trying to avoid IDENTITY.

Comment: @Teju MB you can try a database trigger which would fire on every row save & increment itself but that requires some programming logic to check the last row & add 1 to it .

Answer (score 0):

Change the way your trigger works. Something like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_FuncIncPNR(@ID int)
RETURNS varchar(20)
BEGIN
Declare @Retval varchar(20),
        @No varchar(4)
Select @No = convert(varchar(4), @ID)
while Len(@No) < 4
    Select @No = '0' + @No      

Select @Retval = 'PNRRESA' + @No
RETURN @Retval
END
```

You will notice there is a parameter field

Change your table create to this

```
CREATE TABLE PNRDetails(PNRNo AS (dbo.fn_ShowPNRNo(wID)), wID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, customerNo INT)
```

That should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for the kind response, Bu 1 drawback with the identity is if i insert any value to the table and if any point i ROLLBACK, The gap is created, So i am trying to avoid IDENTITY..